# How to tell if a file has no associated icon

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using the **SHGetFileInfo** api to get a handle to and display the icon associated with a particular file.

If the file has no icon associated with it Windows will return you the default one that it uses in explorer for unknown file types.  In this case I **don't** want to display the icon.

How can I tell if the file has no associated icon and Windows is giving me back the default one?

On my system `SHFILEINFO.iIcon` is always equal to 3 in this case but i'm not sure how reliable that is and I expect there is a better way to check this.

Edit: I am targeting Windows XP and upwards

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which OS versions are you targeting? If you can assume Vista and later, there's an API [SHGetStockIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205(VS.85).aspx) that you may find useful.

```
SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_DOCNOASSOC, SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX, &sii)
```

will return the icon index you're looking for in sii.iSysImageIndex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing a fictitious filename with an unknown extension to SHGetFileInfo(), keep track of which icon index it reports, and then compare that index to your real files.

Comment: You never know when the user will install some other application that registers that fictitious extension.

Comment: You cold simply query the Registry for the registered file extensions beforehand, and then pick one that does not exist yet.  Or dynamically generate a file extension randomly, check if it exists, and re-generate if needed (similar to how GetTempFileName() does when its uUnique parameter is set to 0).